# Powershell script issue

Tags: powershell

I am having an error with the script below:

```
$server_names = Get-Content "C:\ArchivedFolders.txt"
Foreach ($server in $server_names){
             Copy-Item "\\$server\C$\Mail\*" -Destination "\\10.100.101.50\mail\$server\" -Recurse
}
```

The purpose of the script is to copy a file from numerous folders and place them into numerous other folders.  The error is below.

```
Copy-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Illegal characters in path.
At C:\mass_fetch.ps1:3 char:23
+              Copy-Item <<<<  "\\$server\C$\Mail\*" -Destination "\\10.100.101.50\mail\$server\" -Recurse
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell without actually look into what you pass as paths. Do below test: copy a line from file -> $server="pasteLineHere" -> dir "\\$server\c$\Mail". You might have blank space, invalid, or invisible characters in your server names. Also make sure your text file is in proper encoding.

Comment: Why not remove the asterisk (*)? With -Recurse you're already copying everything.

Comment: What does $server_names actually contain, after the Get-Content?  Is it a collection of strings?  Try feeding it to "get-Member" to find out.

Comment: You might have success with `Copy-Item -LiteralPath`.  You might also have success with this advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482771/powershell-copy-fails-without-warning

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to escape the `C$` in your source path. Your string is double-quoted, so PowerShell might think `$\` is a variable.

```
$server_names = Get-Content "C:\ArchivedFolders.txt"
Foreach ($server in $server_names)
{
    Copy-Item "\\$server\C`$\Mail\*" -Destination "\\10.100.101.50\mail\$server\" -Recurse
```

}